# nodemon not installed properly

Tags: javascript, npm, nodemon

I have been trying to install nodemon for my application by using the command:

```
npm install nodemon -g
```

And the following is the output I have received:

```
changed 116 packages, and audited 117 packages in 8s

16 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

However, when I run `nodemon -v`, it is showing error. Can someone help?

Comment: What error do you obtain?

Answer (score 1):

Below are some solutions

1. This is how you can install nodemon

```
npm install -g nodemon
```

after that you have to run this command: `npm run dev`
here dev is (script) server name

2. after that if you are facing error like
   " 'nodemon' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
   operable program or batch file. "
   Then after install nodemon globally write below command:

```
npm config get prefix
```

in output you will get PATH and then past this path in to the Environment Variables and it solved

Restart the terminal and run this command

```
nodemon run dev
```